# Moved concrete5 website, and now the custom theme will not work

Tags: ubuntu, lamp, bitnami, concrete5

I've been fighting with moving an existing site from GoDaddy Windows 2012 to Amazon Ubuntu Instance, and no matter how many different ways I try (Bitnami Lamp, Bitnami Concrete5 AMI, direct install, direct copy-over, etc), the custom theme will not work.  The default themes work, and the site works fine then.

The message I get:

```
File /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/updates/concrete5.6.3.3/concrete/themes/pndc/default.php not found. All themes need default.php and view.php files in them. Consult concrete5 documentation on how to create these files.
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on, or how to debug the issue?

Comment: Can you verify that theme actually exists at /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/themes/pndc/ or possibly in /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/packages/*/themes/pndc/ somewhere? If it does my first guess would be permissions are incorrect on those files, if it doesn't exist in those locations then something probably didn't copy correctly.

Comment: Also can you double check permissions on the directories and files?

Comment: It is at /opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/themes/pndc/, and I checked and re-checked the contents of the theme (which works on the original site at pndc.us), and the file permissions.

Comment: I'm surprised no one knows how to debug this.  I've asked on Concrete5, and a few other places, and it always ends up a ghost town.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got this worked out by moving the concrete5 update "core" to the /concrete/ directory, and out of the upgrade folder.   I then changed the app version and the installed app version to match, etc.  This seemed to correct the issue, as I can now navigate and use the custom theme.